# Website getting cut off on iPad only

Tags: css, ipad

My site is live at http://brand2o.com/. The site is responsive, and works fine at any size on every desktop browser I try and on my Android phone, but the problem is that on an iPad, the right side of the header gets cut off so it says "Licensing P" instead of "Licensing Portal."

[image]

[image]

I'm having trouble figuring out where the problem lies because I can't replicate it on desktop — Chrome's device mode actually shows it having too MUCH room on the right and the website not centering instead!

[image]

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Looking more closely, it looks like the iPad is giving each navigation item (they're flexbox children) equal width, and messing with flex-basis and flex-grow don't make any difference. I can't find anything about it but is this any kind of known bug? Again, it looks fine everywhere else, including desktop Safari.

Comment: Are you sure you are not zoomed in? I checked on the ios sim it looks fine

Comment: Positive... If I try zooming out, it still gets cut off at "Licensing P."

Comment: @Eriyu few elements are overflowed a lot to the right. If you scroll to right you will see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: The `li`s were set to `width: 100%;` for when the navigation collapses, and I should have overwritten it in the media query for bigger screens. I added `width: auto;` and it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Some of this issues are related to version of the OS and Safari also. What I do on this instances, if you connect your iPad to your MAC you will be able to inspect the HTML and CSS and figure the issue out.

[Debug apple devices](http://appletoolbox.com/2014/05/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/)

[Another site](https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/concepts/mobile-debugging/mobile-debugging.html)

Hope this help!
Regards

Comment: Thank you! I did this and discovered that the navigation links is being forced to be equal widths, so in addition to "Licensing Portal" getting cut off, "About" and "Team" have too much space. Still not sure why or how to fix it though...